# Fastest way to count lines in a file

Tags: batch-file

I have huge CSV file, which I want to know the **total number of rows** in which. Currently I am using something like this, which works perfectly, but it's slow:

```
FIND /c ";" FILENAME.csv
```

But I dunno if that's the fastest way to iterate through all lines in a CSV. Any suggestions or method you can teach me? My CSV files have over 100 000 lines.

PS: Please can you include the execute time aswell?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%# in ('find /c /v "" ^< FILENAME') do set "linescount=%%#"
echo %linescount%
```

Comment: Why is the delims = : rather than ; ? And why is the token set at 1? Why is the ^< stand for? **Thank you!**

Comment: @svacxpython - delims is delimiter from the output of the executed command and split it ,Parts are taken with the tokens. `^<` is an escaped input redirection so it will be executed in the for loop body.Need to be escaped because it have bigger priority than the for loop.